# Connect to SQL server from localhost

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I have a newly set up LAMP system for testing a website I am developing. School has supplied a database that uses a phpmyadmin webinterface. If I host the website on the domain I have been assigned by school, everything works fine, but if I host the same files locally it get the following error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Having read up as much as I could, I suppose some setting restricts my access to an external database when hosting locally, but I am lost as to how to fix this.

I know of the my.cnf file but the skip-networking, and bind-address options were already commented out. Also, I checked that both httpd and mysqld are running.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the local server? via script or a mysql client? Also what is the status of your local mysql server. try running mysql.server status

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am hosting all my html and php on the local server (my desktop computer) and my database is hosted on some other server. So I am not sure if mysql status should tell you anything.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to SQL Server if your school uses phpMyAdmin (which is a MySQL database)??

Comment: FreshPrinceOfSO, the poster wrote that the school-supplied database uses phpMyAdmin, so the subject is almost certainly not meant as "[MS-]SQL Server" but "[My]SQL Server".

Answer (score -2):

Odds are very good that the school's database doesn't allow connections from remote IP addresses. Has your instructor specifically told you that you should be able to connect?

To fix it, you'd have to have the system administrator open it up for you.

When you say you edited my.cnf, on what machine did you make those changes? Your local LAMP system or on the school's database server (or convince them to give you VPN access).

Comment: Perhaps those who downvoted me could reply to state what I wrote that was wrong...